# How to reduce line for viewchild in angular 8?

Tags: typescript, angular6, angular7, angular8

I have lot of viewchild line in my project. How to reduce the line. Any way is there?

Please help to find the solution.

app.component.ts:

```
@ViewChild('pRef') pRef: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('Ref') Ref: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('pR') pR: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('ef') ef: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('main') main: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('power') power: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('current') current: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('volt') volt: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('rm') rm: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('wire') wire: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('cable') cable: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('on') on: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('off') off: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('amp') amp: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('short') short: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('cap') cap: ElementRef;
```

Comment: You can look at  this link (about @ViewChildren, QueryList ) https://netbasal.com/understanding-viewchildren-contentchildren-and-querylist-in-angular-896b0c689f6e

Comment: @Caro: Very difficult to understand..Can you edit my script in stackblitz?I mean any example demo

Comment: Could you provide your code on stackblitz, to see what your @ViewChild are used for please ?

Comment: @Caro: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-viewchild-example-z4eyjr?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a good sigh which shows that your `app.component.ts` knows and does too much. Probably it would be great to split responsibility and delegate some logic to another child components.
Or you could create a Directive (ex. CollectorDirective), attach it to all DOM elements which you want to get (like: `<someComponent your-directive-selector></someComponent>`), and in your `app.component.ts` you could use something like this:
`@ViewChild(CollectorDirective) allElements: QueryList<CollectorDirective>`;
and in `this.allElements` you will get an array of children who has CollectorDirective attached. But without context it is not clear if it is exactly what you need and if it would work for certain use case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Can you create example in stackblitz?

Comment: Something like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rfyz7z

Answer (score 0):

According to your stackblitz, to modify all the elements, you could create a directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myDiv]'
})
export class TextTransform implements AfterViewInit {

    constructor(private elem: ElementRef) {}

     ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.elem.nativeElement.innerHTML = ' !!My new Text!!';
     }
}
```

And apply the directive on element:

```
<p myDiv> Start</p>
```

[Here the example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-viewchild-example-zn9ypb)

Comment: You have written only for single..How we can use multiple element reference?